# Can DHCP and NAT co-exist?

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, port-forwarding, nat, upnp

I am using a [U.S.Robotics 9108](http://www.usr-emea.com/support/s-prod-template.asp?loc=emea&prod=9108) to share ADSL Internet access via both LAN ports and WiFi.

Is there a way to allow each Windows 7 PC connected to it to handle its own port forwarding needs, rather than setting static internal IPs outside DHCP's range, and manually assigning forwarding ports in 9108's configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The router in question appears to support UPnP for port forwarding, so any applications that supports that mechanism will be able to handle it themselves.

Comment: I've found the option and enabled it. Applications utilized UPnP and found their way out successfully, adding and removing port forwarding rules automatically. Thanks!

Comment: This is not actually considered port forwarding. It also has a lack of authentication that opens up your network to a multitude of attacks. You really only should use this if you have no other choice.

Comment: How this is not considered port forwarding? Because of it's temporary nature? The result it's the same. Bad things can happen from the fixed rules too, that's why there are software firewalls for someone to use. I can't change port forwarding rules each time I connect different PCs and the router has a limit on how many rules one can create, for me to be able to include all possible scenarios by forcing PCs to use a specific IP like without UPnP.

Answer (score -1):

Port forwarding can only be managed by the device doing the routing. There is no way around this.